# Getting others' posts on a Facebook page's timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using https://graph.facebook.com/JellyBelly/posts (with an access token) to get all the posts on a page's timeline. However, I'm getting only posts made by the page itself.

1. How can I also get posts by others?
2. Could it be that my query also returns posts the page made on other pages/users? I'm not sure it does, but want to know if my query is supposed to only retrieve posts from this page's timeline?

Comment: Why was it voted down? What's wrong?

Comment: I think you were likely voted down because the same page of the documentation which tells you how to access `/posts` also tells you how to access `/feed`

Comment: I didn't know `/feed` was the answer. I thought it's used for getting the news feed, i.e updates from pages/users it's subscribed to. That's not a reason for voting down the question, the one who did that could just answer it instead, like you and the one below did...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/PAGE_ID/posts` give the Page's own posts as described at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/

To get posts by others you need

```
/PAGE_ID/feed
```

or in your case

```
/JellyBelly/feed
```